# Angular2: issues displaying an object in a template

Tags: angular, angular2-template

I'm trying to display a Product which I get from a local server in a template of my Product component.  This template is supposed to be displayed in the template of my `app.component`.  I can successfully instantiate a `productModel` instance from within my `app.component.ts` controller but when I try to display the product in a table on my `app.component.html` template I get the following error:  Any idea where I can look for the issue?

My error:

> error_handler.js:48EXCEPTION: Error in ./ProductComponent class ProductComponent - inline template:8:4 caused by: Cannot read property 'Description' of undefinedErrorHandler.handleError @ error_handler.js:48
>       error_handler.js:50ORIGINAL EXCEPTION: Cannot read property 'Description' of undefinedErrorHandler.handleError @ error_handler.js:50
>       error_handler.js:53ORIGINAL STACKTRACE:ErrorHandler.handleError @ error_handler.js:53
>       error_handler.js:54TypeError: Cannot read property 'Description' of undefined
>           at _View_ProductComponent0.detectChangesInternal (component.ngfactory.js:128)
>           at _View_ProductComponent0.AppView.detectChanges (view.js:233)
>           at _View_ProductComponent0.DebugAppView.detectChanges (view.js:338)
>           at _View_AppComponent0.AppView.detectViewChildrenChanges (view.js:259)
>           at _View_AppComponent0.detectChangesInternal (component.ngfactory.js:126)
>           at _View_AppComponent0.AppView.detectChanges (view.js:233)
>           at _View_AppComponent0.DebugAppView.detectChanges (view.js:338)
>           at _View_AppComponent_Host0.AppView.detectViewChildrenChanges (view.js:259)
>           at _View_AppComponent_Host0.detectChangesInternal (host.ngfactory.js:33)
>           at _View_AppComponent_Host0.AppView.detectChanges (view.js:233)ErrorHandler.handleError @ error_handler.js:54
>       error_handler.js:57ERROR CONTEXT:ErrorHandler.handleError @ error_handler.js:57
>       error_handler.js:58DebugContextErrorHandler.handleError @ error_handler.js:58
>       zone.js:388Unhandled Promise rejection: Error in ./ProductComponent class ProductComponent - inline template:8:4 caused by: Cannot read property 'Description' of undefined ; Zone:  ; Task: Promise.then ; Value: ViewWrappedError TypeError: Cannot read property 'Description' of undefined
>           at _View_ProductComponent0.detectChangesInternal (/AppModule/ProductComponent/component.ngfactory.js:128:62)
>           at _View_ProductComponent0.AppView.detectChanges (http://localhost:4200/main.bundle.js:56051:14)
>           at _View_ProductComponent0.DebugAppView.detectChanges (http://localhost:4200/main.bundle.js:56156:44)
>           at _View_AppComponent0.AppView.detectViewChildrenChanges (http://localhost:4200/main.bundle.js:56077:19)
>           at _View_AppComponent0.detectChangesInternal (/AppModule/AppComponent/component.ngfactory.js:126:8)
>           at _View_AppComponent0.AppView.detectChanges (http://localhost:4200/main.bundle.js:56051:14)
>           at _View_AppComponent0.DebugAppView.detectChanges (http://localhost:4200/main.bundle.js:56156:44)
>           at _View_AppComponent_Host0.AppView.detectViewChildrenChanges (http://localhost:4200/main.bundle.js:56077:19)
>           at _View_AppComponent_Host0.detectChangesInternal (/AppModule/AppComponent/host.ngfactory.js:33:8)
>           at _View_AppComponent_Host0.AppView.detectChanges (http://localhost:4200/main.bundle.js:56051:14)consoleError @ zone.js:388
>       zone.js:390Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: Error in ./ProductComponent class ProductComponent - inline template:8:4 caused by: Cannot read property 'Description' of undefined(…)consoleError @ zone.js:390

My product component template:

```
<table class="table-responsive">
<tr>
<th>Description</th>
<th>POS Description</th>
<th>POS Price</th>
<th>Stock On Hand</th>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>{{product.Description}}</td>
<td>{{product.POSDescription}}</td>
<td>{{product.POSPrice}}</td>
<td>{{product.StockOnHand}}</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

My product component controller:

```
import { Component, OnInit, Input } from '@angular/core';

import { ProductModel } from '../../models/product.model';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-product',
  templateUrl: './product.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./product.component.css'],
  host: {
      class : 'row'
  }

})
export class ProductComponent implements OnInit {
    @Input() product: ProductModel;

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

}
```

My `app.component` template:

```
<div class="row">
<div class="col-md-6 col-md-push-3">
<form class="form-horizontal" role="form">
    <div class="form-group">        
        <input type="number" class="form-control" id="barcode" placeholder="Enter Barcode" #barcode>    
    </div>
    <button class="btn btn-submit btn-block" (click)="submitBarcode(barcode)">Submit</button>
</form>
</div>
</div>
<div class="row">
    <app-product [product]="product"></app-product>-->
</div>
```

My app component controller:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

import { RestService } from "./services/rest.service";
import { ProductModel } from "./models/product.model";


@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {

    product: ProductModel;

    constructor(private restService: RestService){

    }

submitBarcode(barcode: HTMLInputElement){

    this.restService.getProduct(barcode.value)
    .subscribe(
    (res) => {
        this.product = new ProductModel(res.BaseURI, res.CustomError, res.ProviderName, res.RequestFormData, res.RequestURI, res.ResponseCode, res.AvgQty1, res.AvgQty2, res.AvgQty3, res.BarCode, res.Description, res.POSDescription, res.POSPrice, res.ProductCode, res.PurchCount, res.StockOnHand);
        console.log("returned product description: " + this.product.Description);
        //console.log(res);
    },
    (res) => {
        console.log("failure" + res);
    }
    );
    //console.log("product: " + product);
}

}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's because `product` is not defined until your http call is finished. You can use safe navigation operator (`?`) to protect your template from getting current error until your data arrive:

```
<table class="table-responsive">
<tr>
<th>Description</th>
<th>POS Description</th>
<th>POS Price</th>
<th>Stock On Hand</th>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>{{product?.Description}}</td>
<td>{{product?.POSDescription}}</td>
<td>{{product?.POSPrice}}</td>
<td>{{product?.StockOnHand}}</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

You can also use `NgIf` directive which will add your table to DOM after http call is finished:

```
<table *ngIf="product" class="table-responsive">
<tr>
<th>Description</th>
<th>POS Description</th>
<th>POS Price</th>
<th>Stock On Hand</th>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>{{product.Description}}</td>
<td>{{product.POSDescription}}</td>
<td>{{product.POSPrice}}</td>
<td>{{product.StockOnHand}}</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot @Stefan Svrkota I learnt something very useful from you today:)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `*ngIf` as this:

```
<table *ngIf="product" class="table-responsive">
 <tr>
  <th>Description</th>
  <th>POS Description</th>
  <th>POS Price</th>
  <th>Stock On Hand</th>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>{{product.Description}}</td>
  <td>{{product.POSDescription}}</td>
  <td>{{product.POSPrice}}</td>
  <td>{{product.StockOnHand}}</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```